# How does heroku add so many subdomains?

Tags: heroku, amazon-web-services, dns

So I'm trying to figure out how Heroku can create so many subdomains like http://social-login-in-rails.herokuapp.com. I know they are a reseller for AWS, so every time someone creates an app do they just add a route53 entry? Is this scalable? Or do they have some sort of system where they route all of their subdomains with some kind of database lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, [by default you can put 10,000 'subdomains' in a route53 zone](http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Route_53_limits) ('heroku.com'). That's not a hard limit, as the FAQ indicates.

In the case of Heroku, they don't use Route53 for their domain:

```
$ dig +nocmd heroku.com any +multiline +noall +answer
;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode.
heroku.com.     449 IN SOA ns1.p19.dynect.net. admin.easydns.com.
heroku.com.     21599 IN NS ns3.p19.dynect.net.
heroku.com.     21599 IN NS ns4.p19.dynect.net.
heroku.com.     21599 IN NS ns2.p19.dynect.net.
heroku.com.     21599 IN NS ns1.p19.dynect.net.
```

(some lines of the above are snipped for clarity)

It appears Heroku uses a wildcard entry for all the subdomains. The first application certainly exists and the second one certainly does not (as of this writing).

```
$ dig +nocmd httpcats.herokuapp.com any +multiline +noall +answer 
httpcats.herokuapp.com. 299 IN CNAME us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
$ dig +nocmd cowcowcow.herokuapp.com any +multiline +noall +answer 
cowcowcow.herokuapp.com.    299 IN CNAME us-east-1-a.route.herokuapp.com.
```

Hitting the endpoint for cowcowcow.herokuapp.com gives a 404. This all makes sense, as Heroku discusses how they use a "[web router](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works#http-routing)", which is a fancy/intelligent load balancer.